# Jquery how to add last typed character

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I made this code:

```
$('.change').keydown(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('.'+id).text(value);
});
```

It is working fine with 1 flaw. When i type something it doesn't update my last inserted character. So when i start typing "Test case" the div is filled alright although it stops with "Test cas". As you can see i am missing the last character.

How can i make this so that the last character is added?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you should use the event keyup and not keydown.

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the event to `keyup` it will work...

```
$('.change').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.'+id).text(value);
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/84/